Good battery, but UPS fails to do its job
I have a not-so-old APC Back-UPS 1400 (model BX1400U).
It uses 2 x 12 V / 7 Ah batteries. The original batteries are dead (voltmeter says less than 5 Volts, ultra dead). I bought 2 new batteries (12 V, 7 Ah).
With the new batteries, the UPS can power a 90 Watts load during only 2.5 minutes (should be more than 40 minutes). After that, the PowerChute software says the batteries are empty (0 % to 2 % charge). Same diagnosis with Nut (Linux).
If I then put the "empty" batteries into an old APC Back-UPS CS 650 (one at a time), they can power the same 90 Watts load during a little more than 30 minutes. I did it twice, same results.
Can anyone explain what can be the problem?
Or suggest some tests/improvements/etc?
 
 
 

When the batteries are full, on the screen capture above we can see at the same time "Battery discharged" and 100.0 % for the battery charge.
And when the UPS is disconnected from the main, after 2.5 minutes the battery charge is 0 %. Replugging the main slowly make the battery charge goes from 0 to 100 in about 4 hours.

I found only one article suggesting that some kind of calibration could be done for the run-time: community.se.com/t5/APC-UPS-for-Home-and-Office-Forum/Back-UPS-Pro-1500-Battery-Calibration-Estimated-Run-Time/td-p/293195

Short answer : APC people design crap products (in case anyone still had a doubt).
Complete answer : this UPS calculate when to shut down (instead of measuring), based on battery installation date, whatever the real battery capacity.
So if you connect a new and/or bigger battery, this will change nothing. Geniuses.
With APC software "Serial Shutdow" I updated the battery installation date, and the remaining time switched from 5 minutes to 161 minutes in a snap.
The notice to change the installation date is not written on any manual from APC (I checked the UPS manual, and the battery manual).
